# Automate Ubuntu Provisioning

Tags: ubuntu

Could anyone point me the best application used to provision Ubuntu (Unattended installation)? If possible point me some nice tutorials.

Comment: Looks like Ubuntu uses [kick start files](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/automatic-install.html) so you're probably interested in using that in conjunction with [Cobbler](http://www.cobblerd.org/) or [Spacewalk](https://fedorahosted.org/spacewalk/)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/122505/how-do-i-create-completely-unattended-install-for-ubuntu